# Why is the specified cast not valid when trying to execute a query with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, entity-framework, linq

From this SQL table MY_TABLE (types are [DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413) and [NUMBER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832))...

```
COL1   DATE     NOT NULLABLE
COL2   NUMBER   NOT NULLABLE
COL3   NUMBER   NULLABLE
COL4   NUMBER   NULLABLE
```

... I generated the MY_TABLE class with EdmGen...

```
public partial class MY_TABLE 
{
    public System.DateTime COL1 { get; set; }
    public decimal COL2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> COL3 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> COL4 { get; set; }
}
```

... which I try to query using LINQ ...

```
List<MY_TABLE> items = dbContext.MY_TABLE.Where(el => el.COL2 == 1).ToList();
```

... without success...

```
Specified cast is not valid
```

I have

- [checked the types, they match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169249/specified-cast-is-not-valid-c-sharp-entity-framework)
- [checked the nullability, they match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169249/specified-cast-is-not-valid-c-sharp-entity-framework)
- checked the generated query and executed it, it works

LINQ seems to be failing when trying to map the query to its internal objects because FirstOrDefault, ToList, etc., all produce the same error. Why?

Comment: What type is `NUMBER`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's the Oracle NUMBER Datatype. I edited the question to include that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was from Entity Framework's decimal precision. COL3 and COL4 had too many decimals in the database, which caused the cast to fail.

I rounded up the decimals in the database to be able to get the results in my object.

Comment: @ckuri I will - in two days, when SO will allow it. Unless there is a better answer by then :)